# How many ways are there to distribute 6 passengers into three different hotels?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

6 individuals want to go to 3 different hotels such that each hotel can select zero through 6 people all states are possible. From the passenger's angle, we know that there are $3^6=729$ different ways to do this task. But from the perspective of hotels, how can solve be this problem?

We know that hotel 1 can get 6's and hotel 2,3 zero's i.e. $(6,0,0)$ OR hotel 1 5's and hotel 2 1's and hotel 3 nothing $(5,1,0)$ OR hotel 1 3's hotel 2 2's and hotel 3 1's $(3,2,1)$ OR so on. But this counting method does not yield the correct answer.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm confused.  What does "such that one hotel gets none or all of them" mean?  You counted $(3, 2, 1)$ as a solution, in which none of the hotels "gets none or all of them."

Comment: @Brian tung that is one hotel can accommodate all passengers or in a different situation, gets none of them. $(3,2,1)$ is one of the possibilities in which hotel 1 has 3's and 2 2's and 3 1's among other possibilities.

Comment: A better way to phrase this: each participant stays in exactly one hotel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Paco Adajar's nice answer, you can do a case analysis using $7$ cases, as follows . . .

Let the passengers be identified by ID numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$.

Let $a,b,c$ denote the number of passengers who end up in hotels $A,B,C$ respectively.

Let $\text{sort}(a,b,c)$ denote the triple $(a,b,c)$ rearranged in ascending order.

**Case $(1)$:**$\;\,\text{sort}(a,b,c)=(0,0,6)$.

For this case there are
$$\binom{3}{1}=3$$
ways since

- There are ${\large{\binom{3}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes all $6$ passengers.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;\,\text{sort}(a,b,c)=(0,1,5)$.

For this case there are
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{6}{5}\binom{2}{1}=3{\,\cdot\,}6{\,\cdot\,}2=36$$
ways since

- There are ${\large{\binom{6}{5}}}$ ways to choose the $5$ passengers for that hotel.$\\[4pt]$

  Once the above choices are made, there are ${\large{\binom{2}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes the remaining $1$ passenger.

**Case $(3)$:**$\;\,\text{sort}(a,b,c)=(0,2,4)$.

For this case there are
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{1}=3{\,\cdot\,}15{\,\cdot\,}2=90$$
ways since

- There are ${\large{\binom{3}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes $4$ passengers.$\\[4pt]$

  There are ${\large{\binom{6}{4}}}$ ways to choose the $4$ passengers for that hotel.$\\[4pt]$

  Once the above choices are made, there are ${\large{\binom{2}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes the remaining $2$ passengers.

**Case $(4)$:**$\;\,\text{sort}(a,b,c)=(0,3,3)$.

For this case there are
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{2}\binom{2}{1}=3{\,\cdot\,}10{\,\cdot\,}2=60$$
ways since

- There are ${\large{\binom{3}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes passenger #$1$ plus $2$ other passengers.$\\[4pt]$

  There are ${\large{\binom{5}{2}}}$ ways to choose the $2$ other passengers for that hotel.$\\[4pt]$

  Once the above choices are made, there are ${\large{\binom{2}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes the $3$ remaining passengers.

**Case $(5)$:**$\;\,\text{sort}(a,b,c)=(1,1,4)$.

For this case there are
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{1}=3{\,\cdot\,}15{\,\cdot\,}2=90$$
ways since

- There are ${\large{\binom{3}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes $4$ passengers.$\\[4pt]$

  There are ${\large{\binom{6}{4}}}$ ways to choose the $4$ passengers for that hotel.$\\[4pt]$

  Once the above choices are made, there are ${\large{\binom{2}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes the passenger with least ID number of the $2$ remaining passengers.

**Case $(6)$:**$\;\,\text{sort}(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.

For this case there are
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{6}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}=3{\,\cdot\,}20{\,\cdot\,}2{\,\cdot\,}3=360$$
ways since

- There are ${\large{\binom{3}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes $3$ passengers.$\\[4pt]$

  There are ${\large{\binom{6}{3}}}$ ways to choose the $3$ passengers for that hotel.$\\[4pt]$

  Once the above choices are made, there are ${\large{\binom{2}{1}}}$ ways to choose the other hotel which takes $2$ passengers.$\\[4pt]$

  There are ${\large{\binom{3}{2}}}$ ways to choose the $2$ passengers for that hotel.

**Case $(7)$:**$\;\,\text{sort}(a,b,c)=(2,2,2)$.

For this case there are
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}=3{\,\cdot\,}5{\,\cdot\,}2{\,\cdot\,}3=90$$
ways since

- There are ${\large{\binom{3}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes passenger #$1$ plus $1$ other passenger.$\\[4pt]$

  There are ${\large{\binom{5}{1}}}$ ways to choose the $1$ other passenger for that hotel.$\\[4pt]$

  Once the above choices are made, there are ${\large{\binom{2}{1}}}$ ways to choose the hotel which takes the passenger with least ID number of the remaining $4$ passengers plus $1$ other passenger.$\\[4pt]$

  There are ${\large{\binom{3}{1}}}$ ways to choose the $1$ other passenger for that hotel.

Summing the counts for the $7$ cases gives a total count of
$$
3+36+90+60+90+360+90=729
$$
as expected.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I also appreciate the nice answer which Paco Adajar presented.

Answer (score 1):

Let the three hotels be A, B, C. Suppose hotel A gets $m$ passengers with $0 \le m \le 6$. There are $\binom{6}{m}$ ways for this to happen. Then hotel B has to get $n$ of the remaining $6 - m$ passengers. There are $\binom{6 - m}{n}$ ways for them to do this. By default, hotel C gets the remaining $6 - m - n$ passengers.

Thus, the total number of ways for the hotels to do this is given by
$$ \begin{align*} \sum_{m=0}^6\sum_{n=0}^{6-m}\binom{6}{m}\binom{6 - m}{n} &= \sum_{m=0}^6\binom{6}{m}\sum_{n=0}^{6-m}\binom{6 - m}{n} \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^6 \binom{6}{m}2^{6 - m} = (1 + 2)^6 = 729 \end{align*} $$
as earlier given.

Comment: Thanks for nice and complete answer but this is less intuitive. Can you break the above sum and say for different states how many ways are there, for example, $(3,3,0)$?

Comment: Well, sure. That's just $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{0}$.

Comment: I can't understand the logic behind your answer. If possible, answer for a high school student. I want clearly the number of ways for each possible state.

Comment: Okay. I'll break it down.

So you want to count the number of ways to get the distribution $(m,n,6-m-n)$. First, you need to assign $m$ of 6 passengers to A. There are $\binom{6}{m}$ ways to do this. Then of the remaining $6 - m$ passengers, $n$ of them have to be assigned to B, so there are $\binom{6 - m}{n}$ ways to do this. Thus for $(m,n,6-m-n)$ there are $\binom{6}{m}\binom{6-m}{n}$ ways.

The double summation just means you have to sum that over all possible combinations of $m$ and $n$. We have that $m$ must be between $0$ and $6$, and $n$ must be between $0$ and $6 - m$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to choose $a$ people for the first hotel, $b$ for the second hotel, and $c$ for the third hotel, with $a+b+c=6$, is the multinomial coefficient
$$\binom{6}{a,b,c}= \frac{6!}{a! b! c!}$$
so the total number of possible arrangements is
$$\sum_{a+b+c = 6} \binom{6}{a,b,c}$$
where the summation is over all integer triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a+b+c = 6$ and $a,b,c \ge 0$.  We could work this out, but there is a shortcut.

By the multinomial theorem,
$$(x+y+z)^6 = \sum_{a+b+c = 6} \binom{6}{a,b,c} x^a y^b z^c$$
where, as before, the summation is over all integer triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a+b+c = 6$ and $a,b,c \ge 0$. Now let $x=y=z=1$, and we have
$$3^6 = \sum_{a+b+c = 6} \binom{6}{a,b,c}$$
which reproduces the previous answer of $3^6 = 729$.